# Is there a way to specify an input is a single cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, split, array-formulas

I want to iterate over an array of cells, in this case B5:B32, and keep the values that are equal to some reference text in a new array.

However, SPLIT nowadays accepts arrays as inputs. That means that if I use the array notation of "B5:B32" within ARRAYFORMULA or FILTER, it treats it as a range, rather than the array over which we iterate one cell at a time.

Is there a way to ensure that a particular range is the range over which we iterate, rather than the range given at once as an input?

What I considered was using alternative formulations of a cell, using INDEX(ROW(B5), COLUMN(B5)) but ROW and COLUMN also accept array values, so I'm out of ideas on how to proceed.

Example code:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(
    INDEX(
        SPLIT(B5:B32, " ", 1), 1
    ) = "Some text here"
)
```

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H8vQqD5DFxIS-d_nBxpuwoRH34WfKIYGP9xKKLvCFkA/edit?usp=sharing

Note: In the example sheet, I can get to my desired answer if I create separate columns containing the results of the SPLIT formula. This way, I first do the desired SPLITS, and then take the values I need from that output by specifying the correct range.

Is there a way to do this without first creating an output and then taking a cell range as an input to FILTER or other similar functions?

For example in cell C35 I've already gotten the desired SPLIT and FILTER done in one go, but I'd still need to find a way to sum up the values of the first character of the second column. Doing this requires that I take the LEFT value of the second column, but for that I need to output the results and continue in a new cell. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: There are many documents in which I'd want to use this, the basic idea is always the same: I want to know how to iterate over an array rather than supplying the entire array as a single input to a function. Many of the docs in which I'd apply this contain privacy-sensitive information, but if there's a hidden relevancy to any one particular example I could create and upload one with obfuscated names.

Comment: RalphD, for the volunteers here to contribute their time in responding to these questions, it helps if you make this easier by preparing a sample sheet that they can test and demonstrate a proposed solution in.  And typically your sample sheet would have sample data and a replication of the result you would hope to see, and any attempts you may have made at developing a solution.  This saves everyone from having to each create appropriate test data, when relevant.  See this guide.  Thanks!  https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en

Comment: Please share a sample sheet publicly so we can understand precisely the issue. Also, have you considered using [apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)?

Comment: Apologies, an example is coming right up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ralph, I'm not sure if your sample sheet really reflects what you are trying to end up with, since, for example, I assume you are likely to want the total of the hours per area.

In any case, this formula extracts all of the areas, and the hours worked, and is then easy to do further calculations with.

```
=ArrayFormula({REGEXEXTRACT({C5:C9;D5:D9;E5:E9;F5:F9;G5:G9;H5:H9},"(.*) \d"),
         VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT({C5:C9;D5:D9;E5:E9;F5:F9;G5:G9;H5:H9}," (\d+)hrs"))})
```

Try that in cell E13, to see the output.

The first `REGEXEXTRACT` pulls out all the text in front of the first space and number, and the second pulls out all the digits in a string of " #hr" in each cell.  These criteria could be modified, if necessary, depending on your actual requirements.  Note that it requires the use of `VALUE`, to convert the hours from text to numeric values, since REGEXEXTRACT produces text (string) results.

It involved concatenating your multiple data columns into one long column of data, to make it simpler to process all the cells in the same way.

This next formula will give you a sum, for whatever matching room/task you type into B6, as an example.

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY({REGEXEXTRACT({C5:C9;D5:D9;E5:E9;F5:F9;G5:G9;H5:H9},"(.*) \d"),
               VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT({C5:C9;D5:D9;E5:E9;F5:F9;G5:G9;H5:H9}," (\d+)hrs"))},
     "select Col1, sum(Col2) where Col1='"&B6&"' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' ",0))
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer demonstrates how to use QUERY to get the columns and therefore create a single formula in a single cell, as well as how to concatenate results into a single column which is often useful. Thanks!

Is there a way of doing this without QUERY that doesn't involve scripting a custom INDEX function that can accept arrays as input? With that being said, either way, for now I can just use QUERY and didn't realize this is such an obvious way of selecting columns!

Answer (score 1):

I will also answer my own question given what I know from kirkg13's answer and other sources.

Short answer: no, there isn't. If you want to do really convoluted computations with particular cell values, there are a few options and tips:

1. Script your own functions. You can expand INDEX to accept array inputs and thereby you can select any set of values from an array without outputting it first. Example that doesn't use REGEXMATCH and QUERY to get the SUM of hours in the question's example data set: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NljC-pK_Y4iYwNCWgum8B4NJioyNJKYZ86BsUX6R27Y/edit?usp=sharing.
2. Use QUERY. This makes your formula more convoluted quite quickly, but is still a readable and universally applicable method of selecting data, for example particular columns. In the question's initial example, QUERY can retrieve only the second column just like an adapted INDEX function would.
3. Format your input data more effectively. The more easily you can get numbers from your input, the less you have to obfuscate your code with REGEXMATCHES and QUERY's to do computations. Doing a SUM over a RANGE is a lot more compact of a formula than doing a VALUE of a LEFT of a QUERY of an ARRAYFORMULA of a SPLIT of a FILTER. Of course, this will depend on where you get your inputs from and if you have any say in this.
4. Also, depending on how many queries you will run on a given data set, it may actually be desirable to split up the formula into separate parts and output partial results to keep the code from becoming an amalgamation of 12 different queries and formulas. If the results don't need to be viewed by people, you can always choose to hide specific columns and rows.

Comment: Good answer to your own question!